# Limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-cos(x)}{x^2}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

Is it possible to find the following limit without applying L'Hopital's Rule, but only with some transformations?
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-cos(x)}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: write $$\frac{(1-\cos(x))(1+\cos(x))}{x^2(1+\cos(x))}$$